# How to expose cluster+project values to container in GKE (or current-context in k8s)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

My container code needs to know in which environment it is running on GKE, more specifically what cluster and project. In standard kubernetes, this could be retrieved from current-context value (`gke_<project>_<cluster>`).

Kubernetes has a downward api that can push pod info to containers - see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/ - but unfortunately nothing from "higher" entities.

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved ?

Obviously I do not want to explicit push any info at deployment (e.g. as `env` in the `configMap`). I rather deploy using a generic/common yaml and have the code at runtime retrieve the info from env or file and branch accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the [GKE metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#gke_mds) from within your code.  In your case, you'd want to query the `/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/cluster-name` and `/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id` endpoints to get the cluster and project.  The client libraries for each supported language all have simple wrappers for accessing the metadata API as well.

Comment: Thanks! Used in bash `export PROJECT_ID=$(curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")`